# Simple question: uniform convergence with constant terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I have a sequence that is made up of two part: one that varies with $n$ and another that remains constant, does uniform convergence of the part that varies imply uniform convergence of the whole sequence? That is, each term in the sequence is of the form $$f_n + '\text{stuff}'$$ Similarly for series, if we had something like $$\text{'stuff'} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n $$
If true, what would be a formal proof for something like that?

Comment: $|(f_n+\text{stuff} ) -(f_m+\text{stuff})|=|f_n-f_m|$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a translation of the plane by $-stuff'$ on the Y axis (or more generally on your function's image set) and you'll get back to the uniform convergence of $f_n$ or $\sum f_n$.